# Why navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route is returning null?

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Below is my mainActivity code from my jetpack compose. I'm looking for the current route to show bottom navigation menu accourding to that.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), UIConfiguration {
    private var fontFamily = Poppins
    var isDarkModeEnable by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>()

    companion object {
        lateinit var activity: WeakReference<Context>
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        activity.clear()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activity = WeakReference(this)
        isDarkModeEnable = this.resources.configuration.uiMode and
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
        setContent {

            MonoTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    MainScreen(rememberNavController())
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        isDarkModeEnable =
            newConfig.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
        textStyle(
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            lightColor = Color.Blue,
            darkColor = Color.White
        )
    }

    override fun textStyle(
        fontFamily: FontFamily,
        lightColor: Color,
        darkColor: Color
    ) {
        val fontColor = darkColor.takeIf { isDarkModeEnable } ?: lightColor
        uiElements.apply {
            large = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                fontSize = 56.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            h1 = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            h2 = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            subtitle1 = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            subtitle2 = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            body1 = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            button = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            caption = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
            bottomBar = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                fontSize = 10.sp,
                color = fontColor
            )
        }

        this@MainActivity.recreate()
    }


    @Composable
    private fun MainScreen(
        navHostController: NavHostController
    ) {
        val showBnm = showBnm(navHostController)
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                if (showBnm) {
                    BottomNavigationView(navController = navHostController)
                }
            },
        ) {
            it.calculateTopPadding()
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = if (showBnm) 58.dp else 0.dp)) {
                SetupNavGraph(rememberNavController())
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun showBnm(navHostController: NavHostController): Boolean {
        return when (currentRoute(navHostController)) {
            Screens.Intro.route -> true
            Screens.Input.route -> true
            Screens.Report.route -> true
            Screens.Setting.route -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }


    @Composable
    private fun BottomNavigationView(navController: NavHostController) {
        val items = listOf(
            Screens.Input, Screens.Report, Screens.Setting
        )
        BottomNavigation(
            /**modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .graphicsLayer(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 25.dp, topEnd = 25.dp),
            clip = true,
            ),*/
            backgroundColor = colorResource(
                id = R.color.background
            ),
            contentColor = colorResource(
                id = R.color.bottomBarIcon
            ),
        ) {
            val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
            val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
            items.forEach { item ->
                BottomNavigationItem(icon = {
                    Icon(
                        painterResource(id = item.selectedIcon.takeIf {
                            currentRoute == item.route
                        } ?: item.notSelectedIcon),
                        contentDescription
                        = item.name
                    )
                }, label = {
                    Text(
                        text = item.name, style = uiElements.bottomBar
                    )
                },
                    selectedContentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bottomBarIcon),
                    unselectedContentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bottomBarIcon),
                    alwaysShowLabel = true,
                    selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(item.route) {
                            navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                                popUpTo(route) {
                                    inclusive = true
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                            }
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            restoreState = true
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun currentRoute(navHostController: NavHostController): String? {
        val navBackStackEntry by navHostController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        return navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
    }

    @Preview()
    @Composable
    fun Bnm() = MainScreen(rememberNavController())
}
```

This is the currentRoute

```
@Composable
    private fun currentRoute(navHostController: NavHostController): String? {
        val navBackStackEntry by navHostController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        return navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
    }
```

This function suppose to return the route of current destination but it is returning null. Therefore, I'm not be able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to observe for the current destination, then you can use `currentBackStackEntryAsState()` method provided with `NavHostController`.

Here is an example of using it and get current destination route and display it in `Text` composable:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenTitle(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val currentBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

    Text(text = currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route.toString())
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
ScreenTitle(navController = navController)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ->

```
 @Composable
    private fun MainScreen(
        navHostController: NavHostController
    ) {
        val showBnm = showBnm(navHostController)
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                if (showBnm) {
                    BottomNavigationView(navController = navHostController)
                }
            },
        ) {
            it.calculateTopPadding()
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = if (showBnm) 58.dp else 0.dp)) {
                SetupNavGraph(rememberNavController())
            }
        }
    }
```

You are sending navHostController to the function without assigning it. You can assign it like this:

```
navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
```

This way it will not return null.